# How to make numpy functions accept my object as input?

Tags: python

Suppose I have defined my object:

```
import numpy as np

class Mytensor:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = np.array(data)
```

How do I calculate, for example, the exponential of this object?
That is, if I have `foo = Mytensor(2)`, I want `np.exp(foo)` to return `np.exp(2)`.

Edit:
Thanks for replies! I think I need a bit more functionality, but I'm not sure how to correctly explain it... actually I'm trying to build a computational graph using myTensor class, that is, it also has another attribute: self.parents=[].
If I call np.dot(myTensor1, myTensor2), I'd like it to return a new myTensor3 object, with its data being the dot product of myTensor1 and myTensor2, and its parents being the list containing myTensor1 and 2
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, the simplest way is to do `np.exp(foo.data)`...

Comment: You may want to subclass from `numpy.ndarray`, i.e. `Mytensor(np.ndarray):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
def __array__(self):
    return self.data
```

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

class Mytensor:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = np.array(data)
    def __array__(self):
        return self.data    
foo = Mytensor([2, 3])
np.exp(foo)
```

Output:

```
array([ 7.3890561 , 20.08553692])
```

Comment: Yep I upvote and accepted your answer. do you have some suggestions for my edit question? __ array __ doesn't seem to work if I want to use np.dot

Comment: @Sam-gege can you explain with input two array and expected output and better make new question but if you send here I help you

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69128538/how-to-pass-objects-to-numpy-dot-function if you are interested. Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post another question within 90 mins so I have to use a friend's account

Comment: @Sam-gege I saw this, why don't you send t1.data and t2.data?

Comment: Hi, I'm aware of that, but I want t3 to be another myTensor object, whose data attribute to be the dot product of t1.data and t2.data, Also, most importantly, I want to append t1 and t2 to t3.parents list. so basically all of the above by simply calling t3=np.dot(t1, t2). Is this doable?

Comment: @Sam-gege is this what you search for ? `t3 = myTensor(np.dot(t1.data,t2.data),[t1,t2])
`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want it all to be accomplished by simply calling t3=np.dot(t1, t2), you know, just like how a pytorch behaves, if t1 t2 are torch.tensor object

Comment: Hey @user1740577 I think I've got an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69128538/how-to-pass-objects-to-numpy-dot-function